# Closed-form eigenvalues of a banded Toeplitz matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, toeplitz-matrices

> Let banded Toeplitz matrix $W\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be defined by $$W_{jk} = \begin{cases} m - |j-k| & \text{ if } |j-k| \leq m \\ 0 & \text{ if } |j-k| > m \end{cases}$$ Can one get a closed-form eigenvalue of $W$?

I find that the matrix $W$ can be written as $XX^T$ where $X$ is the following $n \times (n+m-1)$ Toeplitz matrix

\begin{gather*} X = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
 1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 & \dots & 0\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1 & \dots &1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}

but I cannot find any theory dealing with the singular value of a matrix like $X$.

Comment: What is $k$? Is $W_{ij}$ indeed independent of $i$?

Comment: Maybe an example could clarify in particular what is the role of $k$ ?

Comment: Unless $M\le 2$, there's no close form I think

Comment: I MathJax'ed matrix $X$. Please fix it.